# Is there a way to calculate the size in bytes of a string based on the length of the string in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, bson

My plan is store store chat messages between 2 users in an array. So I need to know how many elements this array can have if I cap the text string length at, for example 1000 characters.

Comment: A chat message usually has more data than just the text, e.g. a timestamp and more. I don't think this would be a smart design.

Comment: Use [$bsonSize](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/) the max size of a document is 16MiByte

Comment: So do you think that I should design it be one document per message?

Comment: I don't know the details of your app, but on first impression I would do it like that